# Is there a tool for user behavior tracking for intranet websites?

Tags: user-behavior, usability-testing

I would like to collect data reflecting users activities on one of the intranet websites. I cannot use any of the existing cloud solutions because of potential data breaches.

Is there any user behavior tracking solution which can be installed on-sight, inside of the corporate network?

Comment: Product / tool recommendations are not on topic for this site. There is no single correct answer, options change over the years making such questions and answer invalid over time, and they are prone to attracting spam. We need questions based on specific UX problems that need a solution, which I'm afraid this is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you needed something like Google Analytics, you'd try [Piwik](https://piwik.org) , it's free.

[image: piwik]

PS. I have no connection to this company, but I've used this tool before and had a good experience.

Comment: Cool, thanks! It doesn't have heatmaps and sessions replay, right?

Comment: Piwik has a [free plugin for HeatMaps](https://plugins.piwik.org/ClickHeat#description), for session recording you may try [BigBrother](http://formigone.com/big-brother-js/). I have no idea if BigBrother works, and it would be great if you share your experience as a reply to my comment.

Comment: Do these tools work for you?

Comment: It looks like what I need

Answer (score 1):

You can try using HotJar (www.hotjar.com)

PS. I have not used this personally but i know few of my friends who are using HotJar to track usability and users experience on their website. They also have heat maps.

Comment: This answer may not have much use in the future. It directly answers the question but the question itself is problematic.